# How to check if a character is inside a string or number in java

Tags: java

I tried to make a function that takes one argument (a number) and returns `true/false` if it has `6` inside of it. I know how to do that in python.

In python it should look like this:

```
def six(num):
    num=str(num)
    return "6" in num
```

How do I do it in Java?

Comment: `Integer.toString(num).contains("6")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean check(int x) {
    return Integer.toString(x).contains("6");
}
```